# ggplot2: Add diagonals to grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to tweak `ggplot2` in a way that it adds diagonals to the grid?

Obviously, the default grid consists of vertical and horizontal lines:

```
df <- data.frame(a = sample(0:100, 100, T), b = sample(0:100, 100, T))
gg <- ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = a, y = b))
gg
```

[image: plot1]

What I'm thinking about is to modify the default behaviour to achieve a grid that consists of vertical, horizontal and diagonal lines. A quite messy way to achieve this is to use segments:

```
d <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,0,0,25,50,75),
                y = c(75,50,25,0,0,0,0),
                xend = c(25,50,75,100,100,100,100),
                yend = c(100,100,100,100,75,50,25))


gg + 
  geom_segment(data = d, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), colour = "white")
```

[image: plot2]

This seems to be a workaround. But the actual number of segments needed depends on the range of the data. While one could write a function to calculate the number of segments considering the desired spaces between the diagonals, `ggplot2` will nevertheless treat this 'workaround data' as actual data. This is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 6):

How about `geom_abline`?

```
gg + geom_abline(intercept=seq(-100, 100, 25),
                 slope=1,
                 colour="white")
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know you could give it a vector of intercepts :-) +1

Comment: Indeed, this is even a better workaround. But it gets quite a hassle when dealing with `scale_x_date` for example. Also, while the vertical and horizontal grid lines can be altered retrospectively using `theme()`, `geom_abline` cannot.

Comment: I spent some time looking through the `ggplot2` codebase. I'm not a developer by training or trade, so do take this with a few pinches of salt, but my sense from studying the codebase is that the grid lines are meant to reflect the coordinate system (in the way that, e.g., `coord_polar` creates radial grid lines). So I think there's no obvious way to make the grid lines (properly understood) diagonal, because there's no easy interpretation for diagonal grid lines in the context of a coordinate system.